# display settings in XFCE4

Tags: virtualbox, xfce, xrandr, resolution, display-settings

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running as a guest on Virtualbox 6.0.16. I'm using it with a screen resolution of `1600x917` which is usable but it doesn't utilize my whole screen as my host screen is 1920 x 1080 and it would be great if I could maximize usage of my screen real estate - even when working on the guest (95% of the time).
Now, I've got XFCE4 running on my guest but can't launch the `display-settings` as I get:

```
$ xfce4-display-settings 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Two things:

1. How can I fix this

or

2. How can I modify the screen resolution in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xrandr` in the terminal to change the screen size

```
xrandr --size 1920x1080
```